# What does the question mark do in an Angular isolate scope binding?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have read a lot of articles explaining the difference between `@`, `=` and `&`.  I've seen a lot of people using `=?` in their code.  What does this mean?

Unfortunately, I can't seem to search on Google or SO for an answer because search engines ignore special characters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `?` makes the property optional.  Otherwise, you'll get `NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION` where Angular is looking for a property that doesn't exist.

From the docs:

> If the parent scope property doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION exception. You can avoid this behavior using =? or =?attr in order to flag the property as optional.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-